# Understanding JavaScript objects, arrays and the [] operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, operators, accessor

I'm currently researching the nature of JavaScript objects and arrays. I understand that in JavaScript (being an object-oriented language), everything derives from object `{}`.

I'll go through my investigation, step-by-step to help understand my questioning here.
After each assignment to the object or array, the comment beneath it illustrates the state of that variable after the assignment.

*I've tested everything here in the Chrome console.*

```
// These will be used throughout the example.
var obj = {};
var arr = [];
```

Okay, so I can assign things to the object in key/value pairs.

```
obj["a"] = "Hello World";
obj["b"] = "Goodbye World";
// {a: "Hello World", b: "Goodbye World"}
```

In this respect, I can also pass in numbers as a key *(although I'm not sure that this is good practice)*.

```
obj[1] = "Another World";
// {a: "Hello World", b: "Goodbye World", 1: "Another World"}
```

In the same respect, if I want to get back a value from an object, I can use the [] operator.

```
obj["a"];
// "Hello World"
obj[1];
// "Another World"
```

Now lets look at the array object. I can still use the [] operator, but this seems to have a rather odd implementation!

```
arr[0] = "John";
arr[1] = "Pam";
// ["John", "Pam"]
```

And as with an object, I can use the [] operator to get a value back.

```
arr[0];
//"John"
```

But this is where it seems to get a bit odd...given the current state of my array, I can also do the following.

```
arr["0"] = "Mark";
arr["1"] = "Helen";
// ["Mark", "Helen"]
```

So it appears that if I pass in a number as a string, JavaScript will convert this to an array index for me...but what happens when I pass in a non-numeric key instead?

```
arr["foo"] = "Samantha";
arr["bar"] = "Matthew";
// ["Mark", "Helen"]
```

So when I added a key/value pair to the array it had no effect on the array itself, but I can still get the value from that key back.

```
arr["foo"]
// "Samantha"
```

So my question here is: why, and how does the array determine how to store data, either as a key value pair, or as part of the array itself?

My gut feeling here is that because the array is technically a derivative of object, it inherits object's ability to store values as key/value pairs, but also allows values to be stored by index (the nature of an array).

If anyone has any insight into this, I'd be glad to hear it!

Comment: An array is just an object with a special "length" property that is one larger than the highest property name that looks like an integer, and it pretty-prints differently.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the reverse is happening.

Keys in Javascript objects are always *strings*.

For example:

```
var obj = {};
obj[42] = "Hi!";
obj["42"];  // "Hi!"
```

The only difference for arrays is that arrays have a special `length` property based on the highest numeric index that has been set.

Comment: My point was that if you access the array by key, the items you add, do not appear as part of the array, so arr["foo"] = "John" does not add "John" to the array. Presumably because "foo" is not numeric, therefore JavaScript cannot evaluate this as an array index, however I can still access that value via it's key.

Comment: @series0ne: What do you mean by "add to the array"? Other than affecting `length`, that is meaningless.

Comment: I mean that id I do: var arr = []; arr["foo"] = "John"; ... John does not become a member of the array, so basically I'm saying that an array must be an object consisting of key/value pairs, and another data structure consisting of index/value pairs, right?

Comment: @series0ne: Wrong.  The statement `John does not become a member of the array` is meaningless.  All you're saying is that `"foo"` is not a number.

Comment: In particular, indexes _are_ keys.